# Script gives me Syntax error: Bad fd number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, syntax-error

I have a sh script that throws me the 'bad fd number' error, and I can't really find a solution. So this is my script:

```
rr_path='RR/'
filename='sample_generation.txt'
logdir='RR/'

bash RR/compute-RR.sh $filename
```

And this is the error:

> sample_generation.txt RR: RR/nonSingletonesRate.sh: 40: Syntax error:
> Bad fd number

According to the error, something is wrong in the nonSingletonesRate.sh, which is this one:

```
#! /bin/bash

# This script computes the rate of non-singletone events (N-grams with
# n=1,2,3,4) of the input textual file. Computation is averaged on
# equally-sized non-overlapped sub-samples, spanning the whole text
#
# Its results can be used to compute the repetition rate of the text
# as geometric mean by means of /hltsrv0/cettolo/bin/geomMean.pl


bindir=`dirname $0`
irstlmdir=/hltsrv1/software/irstlm/irstlm-5.80.01

# Size of subsamples:
sampleSize=1000

fn=$1
out=`basename $fn`
echo $out
for n in 1 2 3 4
do
ls $fn 
echo "n=$n"
totN=0
totC=0

offset=0
while [ $offset -gt -1 ]; do
offset=`perl $bindir/selectSubSample.pl $fn __subsample__$$ $sampleSize $offset`
cat __subsample__$$ | perl $bindir/word2ngrams.pl $n > __tmp__$$
$irstlmdir/bin/dict -cs=3 -f=yes -i=__tmp__$$ -sort=yes -c=yes >& __tmp.histo__$$
N=`egrep '^>0' __tmp.histo__$$ | awk '{print $2}'`
totN=`expr $totN + $N`
C=`egrep '^>1' __tmp.histo__$$ | awk '{print $2}'`
totC=`expr $totC + $C`
done
echo $totC $totN | awk '{print $0,100*$1/$2}'
echo ""
done

rm __tmp__$$ __tmp.histo__$$ __subsample__$$
exit
```

From what I've seen online, it could be a problem of having a >&, and it should be solved by changing it to >. So changing this line should be enough:

```
$irstlmdir/bin/dict -cs=3 -f=yes -i=__tmp__$$ -sort=yes -c=yes > __tmp.histo__$$
```

But if a do this, then I get the error:

> RR/nonSingletonesRate.sh: 31:
> /hltsrv1/software/irstlm/irstlm-5.80.01/bin/dict: not found

Comment: The syntax `>& __tmp.histo__$$` should be the same as `> __tmp.histo__$$ 2>&1`. I don't know if older `bash` versions don't support the syntax. It is unclear what's wrong if the script expects to find a program `/hltsrv1/software/irstlm/irstlm-5.80.01/bin/dict` but the program does not exist. Please [edit] your question and add information about the system and software you are using. Where do the scripts come from?

Comment: That looks more like a dash error message than anything from bash; since you run nonSingletonesRate.sh with `bash`, it *should* be running in bash, so I don't know what would cause this. I'd recommend replacing the nonstandard `>& filename` syntax with `> filename 2>&1`, and investigating your system's shells to see what's going on there. (Note: I see `echo $SHELL` recommended a lot, but it does *not* tell you anything useful!)